# Django 1.10 run script standalone with Celery - django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet

Tags: python, django, django-admin, celery, django-extensions

I am trying to run script alone with Django 1.10, Python 3.5
and the code will use the Django model.

the script located in the root of Django project.

```
import os
import sys
import django
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "proj.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()


from pipeline.models import *
c = ModelName.objects.all()
```

I got the error of django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet. for the following line of code.
 application = get_wsgi_application()

Previously, I was using Django-extension - runscript to run these scripts to perform data processing task, but it relies on the manage.py, which is not compatible with celery(provide periodic task management.)

Do you have any idea to solve the problem or how to combine runscript with celery?

This is the full error track

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "celery_test.py", line 25, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/home/ah/anaconda2/envs/zorro/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/home/ah/anaconda2/envs/zorro/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 22, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/home/ah/anaconda2/envs/zorro/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/ah/anaconda2/envs/zorro/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/ah/anaconda2/envs/zorro/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 97, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/home/ah/anaconda2/envs/zorro/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 944, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/ah/project/zorro/zorro/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .celery import app as celery_app
  File "/home/ah/project/zorro/zorro/celery.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pipeline.tasks import run_cmc
  File "/home/ah/project/zorro/pipeline/tasks.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pipeline.scripts.celery_test import celery_test
  File "/home/ah/project/zorro/pipeline/scripts/celery_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pipeline.models import CleanedJob
  File "/home/ah/project/zorro/pipeline/models/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .models_general import *
  File "/home/ah/project/zorro/pipeline/models/models_general.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pipeline.models.models_timestamp import TimeStamped
  File "/home/ah/project/zorro/pipeline/models/models_timestamp.py", line 5, in <module>
    class TimeStamped(models.Model):
  File "/home/ah/anaconda2/envs/zorro/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 105, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/home/ah/anaconda2/envs/zorro/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 237, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/home/ah/anaconda2/envs/zorro/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

I solved the problem by deleting all files related to Celery in proj/proj directory(include celery.py, tasks.py and content inside **init**.py) and app_name/tasks.

But how do they work together?

Comment: `get_wsgi_application()` calls `django.setup()` which populates the app registry, so this must be caused by some error during startup. Can you show the full traceback?

Comment: sure, I updated the full error track.